# Get de uma variável pela URL

Tags: jquery

Estou a fazer uma verificação para enviar alertas caso ultrapasse o tempo em que uma tarefa tenha de ser feita.

Código `Jquery`:

```
function session_checking1()
{
    $.post( "./alertaposicionamento", function( data ) {
        if(data == "-1")
        {
           alert('Tem posicionamentos em atraso!');
        }
    });
}
var validateSession1 = setInterval(session_checking1, 10000);
```

Na página `alertaposicionamento` tenho o seguinte php:

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $teste = $row["codigo"];
    $teste1 = $row["Colaborador"];
    $teste2 = $row["FimTarefa"];
    $teste3 = $row["TipoPeriodicidade"];
    $teste4 = $row["Tempo"];
    $teste5 = $row["Ala"];
    $teste8 = $row["nome"];
}

$query = "SELECT iduser, hostname FROM raddb.sessoes
WHERE datafim IS NULL AND hostname = '$teste5'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $teste6 = $row1["iduser"];
    $teste7 = $row1["hostname"];
}

if ($teste4 > $teste3 AND $teste5 == $teste7 AND $teste6 == $_SESSION['usuarioId']) {
    //expired
    echo "-1";
} else {
    //not expired
    echo "1";
}
```

Funciona correctamente e como pretendo. Pretendia fazer uma melhoria, queria pegar no valor da variável `$teste8`, enviar a mesma pela URL e juntar o valor dessa variável à mensagem que tenho dentro do `Jquery` `alert('Tem posicionamento em atraso do (e o valor da variável $teste8) !');`.

Answer (score 0):

Enviei o valor junto com a resposta, desta forma:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if($teste4 > $teste3 AND $teste5 == $teste7 AND $teste6 == $_SESSION['usuarioId'])
{
    //expired
    echo json_encode(["status"=>"-1","value"=>$teste8]);
}
else
{
    //not expired
     echo json_encode(["status"=>"1","value"=>$teste8]);
}
```

E no jquery coloquei assim:

```
if(data.status == "-1")
{
  alert('Tem posicionamento em atraso do '+data.value);
}
```